# Xcode expects UILabel in stack view to have greater height than it is

Tags: xcode, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I am trying place two identically sized sets of a UILabel directly above a UITextField on a UIView. I figured that this would be an excellent use of stack views.

[Here is a screenshot of my elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6sMe.png)

However, for some reason, Xcode seems to expect that the UILabel will be much taller than it should be and results in warnings about the layout.

[Here are the warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJdgg.png)

With the UILabel selected, you can see the outline. You can also see this same sized outline on the other UILabel too, and when selecting the stack view elements it also shows the larger area. When clicking on the UITextField, the outline is shown to begin where the outline from the UILabel ends. Using the 'Resolve Auto Layout Issues' to 'Update Frames' will make the stack view expand outwards to match the size of the outline, however it instantly jumps back to the original size.

[image: Gold highlight around an area much larger than it should be]

Am I misusing or have I misconfigured the stack views? Or is there some other issue going on?

I am using Xcode 7.3 build 7D111g.

Comment: did u give equal width/height consytraints to all labels ?

Comment: @Mr.T none of them have constraints, the stack views are set to fill. When I do set constraints on the labels, nothing changes.

Comment: select all labels and give equal width and height constraint and see what happens

Comment: @Mr.T equal constraints does not seem to affect anything

Comment: since the stack view is set to fill, the other label tries to fill it.
make the stack view smaller

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `label` is filling the `stackview`.

Don't give height constraint to `stackview`. Just add the following two constraints to top `stackview`

1. Top space
2. Center horizontally in container

[image]

`Stackview` will get its height from its content.

Check this updated **GIF** :

[image]

All warning get finished.

Hope this can help.

Comment: If I add a top constraint to the stack view it starts to give warnings. http://imgur.com/a/rIKNG

Comment: Check the updated answer according to your scenario. You only need two constraints for top stackview. See GIF

Comment: So overall this storyboard has two constraints on parent stackview